# Swift: Variables not changing (possible global issue)

Tags: ios, swift, variables, properties

In file A I define my var:

```
var playBegin = false
```

In the same file later on at the end of a function:

```
var playBegin = true
```

In file B:

```
struct pbVariableCheck {
    var playBegin: Bool {
        didSet {
            if playBegin == true {
                println("\(playBegin)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However my property observer here doesn't recognise a change and thus no result is observed? What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-declaring your `playBegin` each time with `var`.Use `playBegin = true` instead while assigning.

You can only observe properties of class or struct not global variable.So if you changing property globally it will not notify to your class which is local and will be notified when you change within the methods of class or instance of class.

```
struct pbVariableCheck {
var playBegin: Bool {
    didSet {
        if playBegin == true {

            println("\(playBegin)")
        }
    }
}
}

//In file A:
class A {
  init() {
     var a = pbVariableCheck(playBegin: false)
     a.playBegin = true //Change the value on instance of `pbVariableCheck`
  }
}
```

Comment: gabbler suggested so and I change it, but the proper observer doesn't update.

Comment: @WilliamClark you need to set property only in stuct not outside struct.First delete all properites `var playBegin = true` and only assign them wihing struct methods or its instance

Comment: Please update your answer to make it a bit clearer, I am having trouble understanding you,

Comment: Thanks a lot, but on var a = pbVariableCheck(playBegin: false) there is an error recognising pbVariableCheck

Comment: You have to call from some class or in Playground.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change var `var playBegin = true` to `playBegin = true`, the former define a new local variable.

Comment: There isn't a change.